# VisualStudio 2010 Freeze after each build

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I Recently I installed VS2010 on my desktop. Everything was fine until I started noticing that after each build **my computer freezes up(for almost 2-5 minutes)**. I removed all the extensions and tried still no luck.

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Can you check the taskmanager and see what is running?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually during each build, I could see ExpansionsXML.xml file is being processed again and again.

I found a Microsoft support article ([support.microsoft.com/kb/956549](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956549)) that has resolved my issue.

What I did:

- Delete the file `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\1033\ExpansionsXML.xml`
- Go to the registry and delete the following key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Languages\CodeExpansions`
- Restart the IDE

I will update more if I see same issue

Comment: After removing ExpansionsXML.xml, VS2010 is working fine without any issue.

Comment: Same worked for me today on VS 2010 Pro SP1 x64. Deleted both .xml file and registry entry.

Comment: FYI, the file and registry entry are supposed to regenerate. Deleting them just takes care of one-time corruption.

Comment: Just removing the ExpansionsXML.xml file and not even needing to edit the registry - worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Install procmon, and see what's happening.  Do you have anti-virus running?  Does the problem go away if you disable it?

Comment: Thanks Chris, procmon really helped to find what DEVENV.exe is doing. Actually during each build, I could see ExpansionsXML.xml file is being processed again and again. 

I found the old microsoft support http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956549. This has resolved my issue.  What I did, 

First delete the file 
(C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\1033\ExpansionsXML.xml). 

Then, go to the registry and delete the following key:
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Languages\CodeExpansions. 

 Restart the IDE. I will update more if I see same issue.

Comment: Is procmon a 3rd party tool or something that comes with Windows or VS2010?  Link?

Comment: No, it's a tool from sysinternals - since bought by Microsoft - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting devenv with the /ResetSettings option?

For spurious waits of a few seconds, I might also look for things like failing network accesses - perhaps with Wireshark and/or Procmon.

The install for VS2010 isn't actual too bad, so an uninstall/reinstall isn't the kind of misery it has been in recent earlier versions.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have already tried uninstalling VS2010. Still no luck.